# Big indent when using long enumeration label

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate

I started out with LaTeX today and already got my first question.
I want to create a question document using enumerations.
However when I give the first enumeration level a long label like "Question 1.", the a), b), c) on the next level are indented so they are behind the Question 1.

Is there a way to disable this feature so less space is wasted?

Also, the compiler directly puts "a)" behind Question 1. if I don't write something behind question 1. How can I fix that one?

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\Large \bfseries Question \theenumi.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\Large \theenumii)}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\large (\theenumiii)}
    \item blub
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item blub
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item blub
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding the second part: Put `~` or `\hspace{0pt}` after your first `\item`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are probably using the wrong tool: I'd better see "Question 1" as a section title. Would you like to add a "real world" example?

Comment: To add to egreg's comment: the next level's entries (a), b), etc.) are not indented. "Question 1." is typeset way into the margin. (Use `\usepackage{showframe}` to see it yourself.)

Comment: Thanks, I started using Sections and Paragraphs at first and then i realized that it was just overcomplicating things and then threw it all away.. a hybrid probably really is the best choice. ~ also worked perfectly. I'll check out the package thx!

Answer (score 2):

Mixing different font sizes like that may be bad for your health and the following may not be your best choice. Anyway... you can make a question list with the package `enumitem` and adjust the indentation manually as you see fit. For example you can go with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{question}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[question, 1]{label=\Large{\textbf{Question \arabic*.}},
  leftmargin=*}       % This avoids "Question" sticking out the margin
\setlist[question, 2]{label=\Large{\alph*)},
  leftmargin=-5.3em}  % Adjust appropriately to get proper indentation
\setlist[question, 3]{label=\Large{(\roman*)}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\begin{question}
\item blub
  \begin{question}
  \item blub
    \begin{question}
    \item blub
    \end{question}
  \end{question}
\end{question}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of example]

Comment: Is there any way to make the leftmargin for the second level dynamic based on the width of the label in the first level?  E.g. -(width of longest first-level label)+1em

Comment: @Gary I am not sure how to produce that. That would mean that lists with different first level label will have different indentation for the second level? You could post a new question and refer to this answer.

Comment: Right, say I have made a newenvironment that sets up the nested lists above, but with a parameter that allows the label in the first level to be specified.  Depending on the width of the value passed to act as the first-level labels, the second-level leftmargin would always need to be tweaked.  An ideal solution would be something where the actual left margin used for the second-level list is dynamically calculated to be a set width (e.g. 1em) from the actual left margin used for the first-level label.